# on MacOS, how to switch to different windows of the same application EASILY?

Tags: macos, shortcut

I found it very frustrating that CMD+TAB switches only between applications and not between windows of the same application.

If I have several windows of Safari open, CMD+TAB will show only ONE instance of Safari.
I know that SOME applications support CMD+` or something like this, but not all of them, some applications have also different keys shortcuts.
I usually set up my key shortcut in preferences as "Move focus to next windows" and sometimes work, but for example, Terminal doesn't accept it.

It's very frustrating, is there a way do move fast between windows?
I also thought that swiping to another desktop was cool, but again, one application with all its windows can stay in only one desktop...

Comment: Terminal works fine with the default key command, or even if you change it to a custom one [even though it says 'Cycle through windows' in the window menu, rather than 'Move focus to next window'.]

Answer (score 5):

Use Command + <kbd>`</kbd> to rotate between windows of the same application.

Use Command + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to rotate between applications.

I'm not quite sure why you find some apps don't support it - I've just tested and it works for me - perhaps it's bound to another action for those applications?